# Story behind the proof of hard theorems

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, math-history

I would like to know the story of how the proofs of some "hard" theorems were reached. More specifically, how did the author get to the "right" ideas (especially when the proof is long and complicated)? Though I'm not particularly interested in the ideas *per se*.

I am mainly interested in the field of analysis but any contribution is welcome.

Let me start with the example of Carleson's theorem on the pointwise almost everywhere convergence of Fourier series of $L^2$ functions, which is an example of a theorem that "everybody" thought it wouldn't be true.

> I tried for some years and then I forgot about
> it before it again came back to me. Then, in the
> beginning of the 1960s, I suddenly realized that I
> knew exactly why there had to be a counterexample
> and how one should construct one. Somehow, the
> trigonometric system is the type of system where it
> is easiest to provide counterexamples. Then I could
> prove that my approach was impossible. I found
> out that this idea would never work; I mean that it
> couldn’t work. If there were a counterexample for
> the trigonometric system, it would be an exception
> to the rule.
> Then I decided that maybe no one had really
> tried to prove the converse. From then on it only
> took two years or so. But it is an interesting example of “to prove something hard, it is extremely
> important to be convinced of what is right and
> what is wrong”. You could never do it by alternating between the one and the other because the
> conviction somehow has to be there.

This is an excerpt from an [interview](http://www.ams.org/notices/200702/comm-carleson.pdf) of Carleson by Raussen and Skau.

Comment: Also, recommendations on biographies of mathematicians that give insight on the origin of their ideas are welcome!

Comment: This is the kind of question that's fun to ask when you meet one of the people who proved the theorem. Otherwise, people rarely discuss this in writing.

Comment: Popular science book: Fermat‘s Last Theorem by Simon Singh

Comment: @Deane That‘s rather unfortunate in my eyes, often the journey to the end result is so insightful but as you say it is rarely recorded in writing. How interesting would it be to read all such discussions by great minds like Gauß or Euler?

Comment: @QiZhu, the Simons Fiundation has made videos of interviews with distinguished mathematicians discussing their career and work. I recommend them. Sometimes a seminar speaker will discuss the history and thought process they went through in their work. Perhaps people can post links to talks where this happened. Speaking about is a lot easier and more fun than writing it all down.

Comment: The details in Fermat's last theorem are worth to be studied because they allow not only to solve this particular problem, but many similar ones. This is not always the case, so it is usually reasonable to focus on the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might enjoy Cédric Villani's *[Birth of a Theorem](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23257776-birth-of-a-theorem)*, a first hand account of his journey to fomulate, and prove, the theorem that ultimately won him the Fields Medal. There is also [this lecture with the same title](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYwydG_aHPE) (and a [Q&A](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akwBX50k504)) on Youtube.

Comment: Seems that for many people the reward that people get for their achievements is more important than the result itself. This is not only the case in mathematics.